# How store data in an associative array from an input field?

Tags: php, html, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to get data from an input field and store them in an associative array in PHP?

For example, if we have two input field on a form. The first one being First Name and second one Last Name. When we input data in both fields, it is supposed to store in an associative array. Let's say we want to input data 5 times and then displays all the 5 first names with its corresponding last name on the browser.

Comment: form > send > `$_POST`

Comment: You're a fair way off being ready to ask a question. This is basic PHP which you can learn about in tutorials. Once you're familiar with the basics, ask a question about some code you are stuck with. Checking it's not a dupe of course.

Comment: @Daan Yes using the $_POST method. Then how do we store it and display all the data on the browser ?

Comment: Go study PHP/HTML  like @James said. This is most basic PHP and HTML

Comment: Do you have 5 first names as 5 separate fields? You can use the form array syntax for that - just use a `name` attribute of `first_name[]` for each of the first-name elements, and `print_r($_POST)` in your post handler to see what it does.

Comment: Only two fields are required.. 
and these data should be stored in associative array when I click submit

Comment: Do you want the ability to add several first names into the one first-name field? You'd usually `explode()` on the space character, in that case. (As you can tell, people are finding your enquiry rather confusing, so if you can add your various comment clarifications to the question, that might help).

Comment: @NileshBhunjun - if you want an array in PHP, you need to define the field as such on the form. A simple test script would have told you as much. This is basic PHP/HTML

Comment: How to define that field ?

Comment: @NileshBhunjun My point is, your question here is pointless as all the information you could possibly want or gain from an answer is already present in half a million tutorials. You are at a very early learning stage, and it's not practical to just keep on asking questions which will *help you learn*. You have to learn through tutorials, then ask a question with code you are stuck with. Also, this question won't help anyone else really.

Comment: Perhaps you people misunderstand my question or I'm unable to express myself clearly.

Comment: I understood your question just fine, don't worry about you not being clear. My point is that you are stuck, and so asking a question, *because* you have limited knowledge of the basic PHP things, and reading some tutorials would benefit you so much more than asking someone to provide you with the code and answer. It being given to you means as soon as you come to the next part of whatever you are doing, you'll need to ask again, and again, etc. If you instead read some tutorials you'll pick up more info along the way and will be able to source your own answers from info already available :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sessions like this:

```
<?php  

    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['marks'])){        

    $_SESSION['info'][] = array($_POST['lname'] => $_POST['marks']);
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['info'])) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['info']); $i++) {
      foreach($_SESSION['info'][$i] as $name => $marks){
        echo '<p>' . $name . '<br>';
        echo $marks . '</p>';
     }
    } 
    }    

    ?>

    <form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "POST">

    Name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "lname"><br><br>
    Marks:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "marks"><br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">

    </form>
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: @NileshBhunjun you got some advance?

Answer (score 1):

**Using the name attribute**

You can use the name attribute in your form to send an array.

For your example (only 3 first names ;-)):

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input name="first_name[]" value="John">
    <input name="first_name[]" value="James">
    <input name="first_name[]" value="Jimmy">
    <input name="last_name" value="Doe">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you submit this, the $_POST['first_name'] will be an array (test.php):

```
echo "$_POST['first_name'][0] $_POST['first_name'][1] $_POST['first_name'][2] $_POST['last_name']";
```

Output:

```
John James Jimmy Doe
```

**Using explode()**

The other way would be to have 2 input fields and split the first name on the server:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input name="first_name" value="John James Jimmy">
    <input name="last_name" value="Doe">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and in test.php:

```
$first_names = explode(' ',$_POST['first_name']);
```

The array will be indexed. To echo them as in the first example:

```
echo "$first_names[0] $first_names[1] $first_names[2] $_POST[last_name]";
```

Output:

```
John James Jimmy Doe
```

Comment: No ! I want to have to only 2 input field. 

<input type = "text" name = "firstname">
<input type type = "text" name = "lastname">
<input type = "submit" name "submit">

I should be able to enter 5 times first name & last name.. It should be saved in an associative array.

Comment: @NileshBhunjun - no, it's not possible. You need to use the syntax Marc gave. If you come up with another method, come back and tell us because we'd love to know how you did it